# Unable to navigate a particular URL in firefox browser.

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Unable to navigate a particular URL in firefox browser. I have written this sample code :

```
public class TestUrl 

{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{


WebDriver fd=new FirefoxDriver();   
Thread.sleep(3000L);
fd.navigate().to("http://www.facebook.com");


}

}
```

The Error i am getting:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   dons.xpi    DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"sp@avast.com","syncGUID":"{0652d9a4-3656-4279-8810-8a89767444bb}","location":"winreg-app-global","version":"10.3.5.39","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://sp/content/common/skin/img/logo-safeprice-48.png","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Avast SafePrice","description":"Safe shopping extension","creator":"AVAST Software","homepageURL":"http://www.avast.com/"},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":true,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\SafePrice\FF","installDate":1474951630115,"updateDate":1474951630115,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":1877359,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"38.0a1","maxVersion":"43.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
>   1474957798423   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
>   1474957798423   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
>   1474957798424   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
>   1474957798425   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your "Selenium Standalone Server jar" with latest version and downgrade your firefox latest version(means use firefox's lowest/stable version), this may help you.

Comment: Hey thanks buddy.. i degraded to Firefox Setup 46.0.1 and its working thanks for the suggestion.